# Define a variable that is dependent to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I want is this:

```
>>> x = 2
>>> y = x+10 
>>> print(y)
12

>>> x = 30
>>> print(y)   #Whatever x is,  y is that number x, plus 10.
40
```

How could this kind of 'dependent variable' be declared in Python version x?

Comment: Isn't this what a function is for?

Comment: What would you like to achieve? If you are doing mathematical computations then use sympy, if you try to implement an algorithm the uye a function.

Answer (score 5):

The only way I'm aware of to do this in standard-library Python is to use a property, so that the appropriate value is calculated every time the attribute is accessed:

```
class Thing(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y_add):
        self.x = x
        self.y_add = y_add

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.x + self.y_add
```

In use:

```
>>> t = Thing(2, 10)
>>> t.x
2
>>> t.y
12
>>> t.x = 3
>>> t.y
13
```

Otherwise, you'd have to have a function call (`y()` instead of `y`) or use something like [`sympy`](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a *function* instead of a variable.

```
def y(x):
    return x + 10
```

So `print(y(x))` will give output of the current value of `x` plus ten.

There isn't a way to do this purely with a *variable*, however. Variables only change their value when you explicitly tell them to.

Comment: Note that: 1. If `x` isn't in scope when the function is declared, you'll get a `NameError`. 2. If it *is* in scope, whenever you call the function without an explicit argument you'll get the original value of `x`, not the current one. 3. The assignment is completely redundant, just `return x + 10`. 4. You aren't following [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Appreciate the feedback :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am aware of that. I'm still learning best Python practice myself, and reading at the moment. If you would be able to edit the answer to address your suggestions, I would appreciate the assistance and guidance.

Comment: I can't really edit it to work - *"This means it will be getting `x` passed in by default each time the function is called"* is simply not true (try changing `x` and seeing what happens). To use a function, you would have to pass the current value in explicitly (i.e. always use `y(x)`).

Comment: Ok, see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in Python are immutable, meaning that they are unchanging over time or unable to be changed unless told to reference something else. In other words, using available data types this is not possible. There is a reason Python is this way - it increases speed and expressibility. There is probably a way to implement what you want to do without a mutable data type.

If you insist on using a mutable data type there are languages which allow this and there may be an importable module or class definition that allows this, but it is highly un-Pythonic.

See: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2000-August/001976.html